# How to convert DateTime object with timezone provided by +hh:mm to UTC (Zulu) in python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have a `datetime` object which looks like this: `2019-05-16 18:45:00+02:00`. I want to convert it into UTC format (take the "timezone change" (+02:00) and subtract it to from the time provided). As a result, I expect to get: `2019-05-16T16:45:00Z`

What is the most elegant way to do it in Python (3.x+)?

Comment: A very useful lib to manipulate datetimes: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: Or you could look there if you need a builtin method: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone